# Is there a pre-built Graspit package for Fuerte?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to install the graspit simulator using the approach [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/10962/how-to-rebuildupdate-graspit-simulator-package/)

sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-graspit-simulator  (replacing "diamondback" with "fuerte")

But the install failed with "Unable to locate package".
Most of the [graspit_simulator](http://www.ros.org/wiki/graspit_simulator)  wiki links are busted.

Does this package exist under Fuerte?  Has it moved?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46020/is-there-a-pre-built-graspit-package-for-fuerte?/) by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2012-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The graspit_simulator stack is not currently released under Fuerte.

The plan is to complete the release and update the documentation in early November 2012.

Note that you can still check it out from source code and compile manually under Fuerte:

sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-object-manipulation

svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/graspit_simulator/trunk graspit_simulator

You might need to apt-get by hand the system dependencies in graspit_simulator/rosdep.yaml (Qt, Coin, etc.)

---

Originally posted by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) with karma: 586 on 2012-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1